# Como poner la contraseña de GitHub en git

Tags: git, github

estoy empezando con GitHub y tengo MacBook, al momento de pegar el git remote, git branch y git push en git me pide el username de GitHub, lo pongo y me pide la contraseña pero me aparece así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] . anteriormente ya hice lo que tenia que hacer: git init, git status, git dad . git commit -m y git status nuevamente. creo que es al ser Apple, ya que con windows no sucede

Comment: Simplemente la tienes que poner, los caracteres no aparecen, pero la contraseña si se está asignando, solo asegurate de poner bien la credencial

Comment: @JonathanPerez ya la ascribe y de iguana forma me da error, me dice esto: remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for

Comment: Ah, ok, si git hub ahora pide que ingreses un token personal, visita el enlace que te da el mensaje y sigue los pasos, una vez crees ese token, ese lo pones como contraseña

Comment: @JonathanPerez ya pude! muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Por seguridad ya no puedes trabajar con Github desde equipos remotos con el usuario y la contraseña, como ya ha dicho @JonathanPerez, debes usar un token, el cual expirará según el tiempo que le pongas. La forma más segura es usar llaves públicas / privadas, es un poco más complejo de configurar, pero luego sólo pones la contraseña que diste a tu llave privada y listo. [Aquí tienes la doc](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) por si te interesa explorar esa  posibilidad.